# Deseo validar el ingreso de datos repetidos en fullcalendar por ejemplo un doctor no puede realizar dos citas a la misma hora y la misma fecha

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, validación, fullcalendar

Estoy trabajando con FullCalendar en laravel
[image: Aqui se muestra los datos ingresados que estan repetidos]

[image: al hacer click en una fecha me muestra un modal para ingresar o verificar datos]

[image: IMgen muestra codigo para recuperar datos]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Peticion ajax]

Comment: El código mínimo necesario para un [mcve] va como texto, además te recomiendo leas [ask], ¿cuál es la duda?, ¿qué llevas hecho?

Comment: Trata de enviar imágenes solo en los casos necesarios y dejar tu código para poder comprobarlo. En imágenes muchas veces es difícil de leer.